# Why is Glob module searching immediate subdirectories when recursive is false?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have functions using glob to identify files for removal. In the first function, the recursive toggle works as intended. In the second function, the recursive toggle is somewhat working... Here's a sample of my code below.

```
for item in glob.glob(myfile_path + '/**', recursive=self.recrsv.get()):
    if item.endswith(".mesg"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, item))
```

This function works as intended.

```
for junk in glob.glob(myfile_path + '/**' + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", recursive=self.recrsv.get()):
    os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, junk))
```

This function somewhat works. Whether `recursive` is set to `True` or `False`, it still goes into the first level of subdirectories and deletes files `*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` . It does *not* go into the second level of subdirectories unless `recursive` is set to `True`.

Note: Recursive is set to a `tk.BooleanVar()` named `self.recrsv` used in a Checkbutton in a tkinter widget.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a workaround for my issue using an if-statement and repeating the glob under it.

```
    for junk in glob.glob(myfile_path + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, junk))

    #The above code will delete the specified junk file within myfile_path.

    if self.recrsv.get()==1:
        for junk in glob.glob(myfile_path + '/**' + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]",
                              recursive=self.recrsv.get()):
            os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, junk)

    #The above code checks the recursive variable, and if true, will recursively delete the junk files.
```

If I do not use the if-statement and simply rely on glob's own recursive check, the junk file will be removed from the first level of subdirectories even if `recursive=False`.

I can probably clean up the code some more to be a bit more if-statement-intuitive, but the problem has been solved. Thank you, @Szellem and @user2357112 for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

With `recursive=False`,

```
myfile_path + '/**' + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

is equivalent to

```
myfile_path + '/*' + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

or

```
myfile_path + '/*/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

However, even with `recursive=False`, this pattern *explicitly says* to search through subdirectories of `myfile_path`, not through the contents of `myfile_path` itself. A pattern saying to search through `myfile_path` would be

```
myfile_path + '/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

(Also, building a glob this way is dangerous, because `myfile_path` could contain glob metacharacters. Remember to use `glob.escape` on components you want to match literally, or pick a search mechanism that doesn't need escaping.)

Comment: `myfile_path + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"` fails to search subdirectories for files that end in the specified extension. It's perfect for the files within `myfile_path`, but not the subdirectories (which is my objective).

Comment: @K.Hess: ...then why did you say that `myfile_path + '/**' + "/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"` "somewhat works"? What do you not like about its behavior? Your question definitely *sounded* like you wanted to stop searching subdirectories.

Comment: I should have clarified, "somewhat works" is stating that the method works on subdirectories 2 levels down and more (myfile_path/dir1/dir2); however, on the immediate subdirectory (myfile_path/dir1), the specified files are deleted regardless of recursive being set to True or False.

Comment: @K.Hess: Are you looking for a single glob pattern that will do a recursive search with `recursive=True`, but only search through `myfile_path` with `recursive=False`? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That is correct. It is successfully working on the first for-statement beginning with `for item`. Files with extension `.mesg` are properly deleted only in `myfile_path`, and are deleted in subdirectories when I set `recursive` to `True`. However, the nastier extension I'm trying to delete changes in sequential order. `.e8754`, `.o8755` for example, so I need to get a little more creative in searching it out.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

"If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by an os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match."

So `**` in `<myfile_path>/**/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` matches exactly one level of subdirectories when recursive is set to false. Because `/` is `os.sep` I assume.

Comment: This doesn't seem to hold true for the first for-statement (the `for item` statement). Files with the extension `.mesg` are deleted in subdirectories only if I set `recursive` to `True`. Otherwise, the `'/**'` seems to be ignored.

Comment: Of course, because in that case `**` is not followed by a path separator so it matches files, but in the second case it is followed by a path separator so it doesn't match files that are not directories.

Comment: So if you want them to work the same way, either add one more `/**` to the first one or remove `/**` from the second one.

Comment: At the risk of sounding dumb, can I ask you to avoid pronouns "first one, second one"? Per your suggestion (I think), I changed the script to `for junk in glob.glob(myfile_path + '/**' + "/**/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", recursive=self.recrsv.get()):
            os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, junk))`. This leads to an odd case where, if recursive is false, the specified file is removed from myfile_path\dir1\dir2, and if recursive is true, the specified file is removed from myfile_path and myfile_path\dir1.

Comment: If recursive is false, the two `**/**/` will match exactly two levels of subdirectories. If recursive is true, then they can match zero levels which means the files that are directly in `myfile_path` are matched.
Btw I meant this with my comment:
`for junk in glob.glob(myfile_path + "*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]", recursive=self.recrsv.get()): os.remove(os.path.join(myfile_path, junk))`

But now I'm starting to understand your problem, because this won't match subdirectories even if recursive is set to true.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This clarifies how ** is working in this script. If there is a way to use an if-statement glob to capture `"*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`, that might be the ideal method. I'll have to look into it as I've not used glob within itself. i.e. `for junk in glob.glob(): if glob.glob....`

Comment: It's ugly but I'm wondering if `myfile_path + "../**/*.*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"` could work. The idea is to start with the parent directory of myfile_path then add a `**/` so match the content of myfile_path when recursive is false and match the content of the parent recursively otherwise. The only problem is that in recursive mode the contents of the parent directory and the contents of the siblings of myfile_path will also be matched. And it doesn't work for the file system root.

Otherwise I don't see any option to solve this with a single glob pattern.

Comment: A puzzle for another day perhaps, as the workday comes to a close on my end. I'll sleep on it and come back to it in the morning.